# java interface instead of implementation

Tags: java, spring, interface

I got a method with a given parameter :

```
public static Map<String, String> validationMessages(Set<ConstraintViolation<EditEmailForm>> failures)
```

and now I would like to add another forms to it, so I surround my all forms with a Form interface and implement it , and change method to this :

```
public static Map<String, String> validationMessages(Set<ConstraintViolation<Form>> failures)
```

now in my Controller I try to use this method like this :

firstly I create a failures object, and do validation

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<EditEmailForm>> failures = validator.validate(editEmailForm);
```

and then try to pass it to validationMessages method :

```
return FormUtils.validationMessages(failures);
```

but I can't do it like this. What is the solution here?

Thanks

Comment: are you using a particular framework? Why doesn't it work? Do you get a particular exception?

Comment: "but I can't do it like this"... hmm why not ? explanation please

Comment: The method validationMessages(Set<ConstraintViolation<Form>>) in the type FormUtils is not 
 applicable for the arguments (Set<ConstraintViolation<EditEmailForm>>)

Answer (score 0):

Change the declaration in your method to

```
public static Map<String, String> validationMessages(Set<ConstraintViolation<? extends Form>> failures)
```

If that does not help, give more details

Comment: The method validationMessages(Set<ConstraintViolation<? extends Form>>) in the type FormUtils is 
 not applicable for the arguments (Set<ConstraintViolation<EditEmailForm>>) - still the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

this problem comes from the fact that java-generics are not covariant. look at this for details

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html

think about this case.

B extends A.

you invoke this method

```
void someMethod(Set<A> as) {
    as.add(new A());
}
```

with

```
Set<B> bs = new HashSet<B>();

someMethod(bs);
```

would this compile, you would be able to add an A to a collection of Bs.

As for your concrete problem. Why would you even have the Form-Class as a generic of ConstraintViolation?